# Is there anything that will remind me that my laptop is in High Performance mode?

Tags: windows, desktop-client

I sometimes turn on High Performance mode on my Windows laptop so games run smoothly. However, too often I forget to turn it off, sometimes for weeks, and assume my battery's being drained by Chrome, low reception, or some other factor. **Is there any utility that'll let me get a popup reminder, say, 5 hours after I turn it on?**

Answer (score 1):

You can give it a try this software is called BatteryCare It monitors the battery's discharge cycles and helps increasing it's autonomy and improving its lifetime.

http://batterycare.net/en/index.html

From the Website:

> **Features**
>
> - Battery's discharge cycles monitoring
>     The advanced algorithm accurately records when a complete discharge cycle is performed.
>     When the configured number of discharge cycles is reached, a notification balloon pops up to remind that a full discharge is required.
> - Complete battery information
>     It calculates the statistical remaining time in laptops that don't support the battery time left information and only list the charge percentage.
>     Shows all the detailed information about the battery, such as wear level, capacities, consumption, manufacturer, etc.
> - CPU and HDD temperature reading
>     BatteryCare constantly monitors your CPU and hard drive temperature, either in degrees Celsius or Fahrenheit.
> - Automatic power plans switching
>     Depending on the power source of the computer, BatteryCare can automatically select the power plan you prefer.
> - Control over Windows Aero and demanding Services
>     Automatically disable the graphics accelerated theme in Windows Vista and/or demanding services that degrade battery lifetime.
>     Once the laptop stops running on batteries, the theme is re-enabled and the stopped services are restored.
> - **Notification area information**
>     It features a compact popup with the essential information you need to quickly monitor. Temperatures, charge status, remaining time and **power plans**
> - Auto-updates
>     No need to trouble in downloading new installers, when a new version is available, the program updates itself.
> - Lightweight in the system

Comment: hope I have answered clearly but as you mentioned im still doubtful with my answer!based on this feature Notification area information
It features a compact popup with the essential information you need to quickly monitor. Temperatures, charge status, remaining time and power plans,Im comfortable to post this answer

Comment: 'I've just edited the post to make it better readable, highlighting the OPs "wished feature" by making it bold. Not exactly what he asked for, but pretty close at least. If there's no solution for a "popup", a reminder in the notifications certainly is the next best thing. Thanks for providing the additional details!

Comment: You welcome :) !

Comment: I just installed it, and it has the option to change the power plan when plugged in or unplugged, but not notify me of a power plan. That'll work for me, so +1, but it doesn't answer the question, so I'd feel wrong accepting it as an answer.